# Async method failing when called

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

I have this method

```
public class WebSearcher : IWebSearcher
{
    private static readonly string _rootUri;
    private static readonly BingSearchContainer _bingContainer;
    private static readonly string _accountKey;

    static WebSearcher()
    {
        _rootUri = ConfigurationSettings.Settings.RootUri;
        _bingContainer = new BingSearchContainer(new Uri(_rootUri));
        _accountKey = ConfigurationSettings.Settings.AccountKey;
        _bingContainer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_accountKey, _accountKey);
    }

    public Task<IEnumerable<WebResult>> SearchAsynch(string query)
    {
        if (query == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("query cannot be null");
        }

        DataServiceQuery<WebResult> webQuery =
            _bingContainer.Web(query, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

        return Task.Factory.FromAsync(webQuery.BeginExecute(null, null),
            asyncResult => webQuery.EndExecute(asyncResult));
    }
}
```

and I call it like this

```
public class Client
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Search();
    }

    private static async Task Search()
    {
        var tasks = new Task<IEnumerable<WebResult>>[100];
        IWebSearcher webSearcher = new WebSearcher();
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            tasks[i] = webSearcher.SearchAsynch(i.ToString());
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tasks[i].Result.First().Title);
        }
    }
}
```

The code stops executing at the WhenAll line.

Comment: What kind of program is it? A console application? How are you waiting for the method that contains the loop to finish? In other words: if you're asking about the behavior of your whole program, you need to show us your program.

Comment: The method that conatains the loop is marked as async and it's a console app

Comment: That's still not enough information. Can you include your actual code? That includes your `Main()` method, the method that calls `SearchAsynch()` and anything in between.

Comment: @svick This is all the code now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to change Search from async void to async Task and then Wait() the result in Main - otherwise, it exits after the task starts, but nothing is waiting for it to finish.

Comment: I've cahnged my client as above but the results come out sequentially which suggests to me that it still isn't asynchronous.

Comment: "Asynchronous" does not mean "parallel". If you `await` each task as it's created, it will execute sequentially. If you want multiple `SearchAsync` calls to run concurrently, call it multiple times and then `await` all the tasks together using `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: @StephenCleary I hope I'm forgiven for being a little confused by all this.  I'm more used to sequential, predictable programming.  It would help if I saw some code to demonstrate this.

Comment: I've updated the code as you say, but it still is sequential.

Comment: @SachinKainth: Your updated code is still blocking (`Result`) on each task one at a time, hence synchronous (you're still not using `WhenAll`). I have an example of `WhenAll` on [my `async` intro blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Comment: @StephenCleary I am using WhenAll in the main method.

Comment: @StephenCleary nice blog - looking into it now.

Comment: @StephenCleary Now the code stops execution at the WhenAll line.  I am missing something big here.

Comment: In `Main`: `Search().Wait();`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27873/discussion-between-sachin-kainth-and-stephen-cleary)